# asp net core 3 Getting BadRequest response on POST action with body content after publish

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm building a website with asp.net core 3 which I'm hosting on a Debian 9 server with nginx as a reverse proxy. I'm running against this issue that my POST requests do work when I run the application locally in visual studio, but when I publish the application and upload it to my server, they suddenly don't work anymore.

This is the controller that I'm using for testing:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Ping()
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Echo(string message)
    {
        return Ok(message);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult FormEcho([FromForm]string message)
    {
        return Ok(message);
    }
}
```

I'm using postman to test these endpoints.

`Ping`:

- using a post request without any parameters gives a 200 both locally and on the server as expected.
- using a post request with x-www-form-urlencoded content gives a 200 locally, but a 400 on the server.

`Echo`:

- Post request with query string parameter returns the message with code 200 both locally and on the server.
- Post request with message as x-www-form-urlencoded content returns the message with code 200 locally, but gives a 400 on the server.

`FormEcho`:

- Post request with message as x-www-form-urlencoded content returns the message with code 200 locally, but gives a 400 on the server.

From this test, I'd think that somehow post requests with body content are rejected on my server. I also noticed from the logs that for the requests that return a 400 on the server, there is nothing in the logs, as if the request doesn't even reach my application.

**Why does my application reject post requests with body content?**

---

EDIT:
Here is my configuration in nginx:

```
server {
    listen        443 ssl;
    listen        [::]:443 ssl;

    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name   51.38.35.10;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log info;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    listen        80;
    listen        [::]:80;

    server_name   51.38.35.10;

    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: _“there is nothing in the logs, as if the request doesn't even reach my application”_ – Then maybe it doesn’t? Check nginx’ logs to see if there is anything going on. You can also try running the application directly on the server (without nginx) to see if it works that way. Also try increasing the log level, so that you can see debug messages.

Comment: If there are no logs about the request on your ASP server, but there are logs in the nginx server, the problem is with your config there. You should post the config, and also any error logs from nginx. Also, nginx can be started in debug mode, where it produces much more useful logs.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Thank you for the suggestion. I included my nginx configuration in the question. I checked the log and there were no messages about the 400 errors. I set log level to info, because I read that 400 errors are logged at info level, but no messages. Only warnings about my self signed certificate. I'll see if  I can start nginx in debug mode.

Comment: @poke thank you, I'll try to run the the application without nginx and see what happens.

Comment: No idea if this is related to this issue but I have seen `Connection 'upgrade'` only with websocket configurations. Try `proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive` instead.

Comment: @poke is onto something, I think. Connection upgrade is very suspicious.

Comment: @poke I tried your suggestion to change Connection to `keep-alive` and it works!! thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ASP.NET Core application does not even log incoming requests (while others work), then it appears that it doesn’t actually get any incoming requests. In that case, it is probably your reverse proxy configuration that isn’t letting these requests through to your app.

I usually use the following configuration for ASP.NET Core applications through nginx:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

That is also the [recommendation from the official ASP.NET Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-nginx).

Setting a different `Connection` header value, in particular `Upgrade`, seems to be a bit problematic. I’ve personally just seen the `Upgrade` value when used with a HTTP `Upgrade` header for WebSockets.

So adjusting the nginx configuration should probably solve your problem.

Note that `Connection keep-alive`