# POST methods are only working on my local machine but not on remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nginx, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I published a WEB API application (.Net Core 3.1) on my Ubuntu 18.04 server and its running behind NGINX.
My GET methods are working on local machine as well as on remote server. But my POST methods are only working on my local machine but not on remote server though I tried many things. I get 400 (bad request) error from remote server. I could not figure out what is the reason behind it. 
Here is my code:

```
 public class MyCls
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
}

[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class NewController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet("MyGetRoute")]
    public string Method1()
    {
        return "Hello from server.";
    }

    [HttpPost("MyPostRoute")]
    public  MyCls Method2(MyCls str)
    {

            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                // PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
                WriteIndented = true
            };

        str.MyString = str.MyString + "  John";
        str.MyInt = str.MyInt + 2;
        return str;

    }

    [HttpPost("MyPostRoute2")]
    public string Method3(MyCls str2)
    {

        return str2.MyString;

    }
}
```

And here is my code in html page:

```
 function postIt() {

        axios.post('New/MyPostRoute', {
            MyString: 'Fred', 
            MyInt: 4,
        }
        ).then(function (response) {
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = response.data.myString + "   " + response.data.myInt;
            console.log(response.Text);
        })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
            .finally(function () {

            });
    }

    function postIt2() {

        axios.post('New/MyPostRoute2', {
            MyString: 'Fred', 
        }
        ).then(function (response) {
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = response.data;
            console.log(response.Text);
        })
            .catch(function (error) {
                 console.log(error);
            })
            .finally(function () {

            });
    }

    function getIt() {
        axios.get('New/MyGetRoute')
            .then(function (response) {
                document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = response.data;
                console.log(response.Text);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
            .finally(function () {

            });
    }
```

Here is my NGINX configration:

```
    server {
    listen        80;
    listen [::]:80;

    index index.html home.html
    server_name   dotnet.xxxxxx.com www.dotnet.xxxxxx.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxx.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxx.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
 server {
    if ($host = dotnet.xxxxxx.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
```

Comment: Since your problem appears after placing your web application _behind_ nginx, could you also share your nginx configuration?

Comment: @poke I added NGINX configration.

Comment: I think you should take a look at your Nginx logs. Add to the first line in your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
After that restart nginx and you should have some log entries.

Answer (score 1):

If a problem appears *after* putting it on a different enviroment, then you should always try to find out if that environment’s configuration is the source of the problem. In your case, the application was working fine locally, so it is unlikely that it will suddenly break when deployed in production. Instead, it’s more likely that the reverse proxy you put in front of this is the cause of your problem.

You can also verify this by checking your application logs. If the reverse proxy is mishandling requests, then they will probably not end up reaching your ASP.NET Core application, or they will end up being malformed. So you should either see nothing in the logs, or some proper error.

In this case, the problem is likely with the following nginx configuration:

```
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
```

You shouldn’t set the `Connection` header permanently to `'upgrade'`. Upgrading the connection is only used when you want to switch the protocol, most commonly when you are using WebSockets. In that case, you would only want to do this on a subpath though, as it will stop normal requests from working properly.

The correct way to set the `Connection` header is to use `'keep-alive'` as you have *also* done:

```
proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
```

You should only set each header once anyway. If you remove the `Connection 'upgrade'` line and only keep the `Connection keep-alive` one, then your requests will likely go through properly.

See also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59238645/216074) for a similar problem that appeared for POST endpoints after publishing.

Comment: Bulls eye!! Commenting out line   "proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';" and restarting nginx solved the problem. Thanks a lot dear poke.